# Extra null value when i try to return a message in postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

When i try to return an error message from my spring mvc controller requestmapping to postman tool , I am also getting an extra  a null value.

My RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getcompanystatus",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<CompanyStatusMaster> getCompanyStatus()
    {
        List<CompanyStatusMaster> companyStatus=userService.getCompanyStatus();
        return companyStatus;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/getstates",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<StatesMaster> getstates()
    {
        List<StatesMaster> statesList=userService.getStates();
        return statesList;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/getcompanies", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public CompaniesPresenter getCompanies(@RequestBody UserDetails user)
    {
    String OrgLoginId=user.getOrgLoginId();
    String password=user.getuPassword();
    String  checkLoginId=null;
    String  uPassword=null;
    String encPassword=null;
    String loginId=null;
    String checkAuthorized=null;
    String checkOrgloginId=userService.getLoginId(OrgLoginId);
    if(checkOrgloginId==null){
        return new CompaniesPresenter("Incorrect loginId..Please enter valid loginId");
    }
    List<Object[]> CheckIdPassword=userService.checkLoginId(OrgLoginId);
    List<Object[]> results = CheckIdPassword;
    for(Object[] obj:results){
        checkLoginId=obj[0].toString();
        if(null==obj[1]){
            uPassword="";
        }else{
            uPassword=obj[1].toString();
        }
        loginId=obj[2].toString();
    }
    checkAuthorized=loginId.substring(0,3);
    if (null != password) {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5();
        encPassword = md5.getPassword(password);
    }

    if(encPassword.equals(uPassword))
    {
        if (checkAuthorized.equals("STE"))
        {
            List<CompanyMaster> companyList=userService.getCompanyList(OrgLoginId);
            if(companyList.isEmpty())
            {
            return new CompaniesPresenter("Sorry..No companies for the user id");
            }
            else
            {
                return new  CompaniesPresenter("select company from the below list",companyList) ;  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new CompaniesPresenter("You are not Authorized");
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        return new CompaniesPresenter("Incorrect Password");
    }


    }
```

My CompaniesPresenter class:

```
public class CompaniesPresenter {
    private String status;
    private List<CompanyMaster> companyMaster;


    public CompaniesPresenter() 
    {

    }


    public CompaniesPresenter(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public CompaniesPresenter(List<CompanyMaster> companyMaster) {
        this.companyMaster = companyMaster;
    }


    public CompaniesPresenter(String status, List<CompanyMaster> companyMaster) {
        this.status = status;
        this.companyMaster = companyMaster;
    }


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }


    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public List<CompanyMaster> getCompanyMaster() {
        return companyMaster;
    }


    public void setCompanyMaster(List<CompanyMaster> companyMaster) {
        this.companyMaster = companyMaster;
    }   

}
```

My postman tool result:
{
    "status": "Sorry..No companies for the user id",
    "companyMaster": null
}

I dont want the  "companyMaster": null. I just want the  "status": "Sorry..No companies for the user id" .I dont know why i Am getting that. please help me..For all the return values I am getting that.Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to your pojo:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class CompaniesPresenter {
    private String status;
    private List<CompanyMaster> companyMaster;
..}
```